# Simplifying a ratio of "two-sided incomplete Beta functions"

Tags: calculus, integration, recreational-mathematics, special-functions, beta-function

Let $0\leq L < R\leq 1$ and $0\leq s \leq T$. Can the following ratio be $\text{simplified?}$

$$ \frac{\int_L^R z^{s+1}(1-z)^{T-s}dz}{\int_L^R z^{s}(1-z)^{T-s}dz} $$

If it helps to assume that $s$ and $T$ are integer-valued, please do!

Comment: **Note:** I call $\hat{B}(x,y;L,R):=\int_L^R z^{a-1}(1-z)^{b-1}dz$ a "two-sided incomplete beta function" due to its resemblance to the [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), $B(x,y;R):=\int_0^R z^{a-1}(1-z)^{b-1}dz$.

Comment: I could get $$
\frac{{s + 1}}{{T + 2}} + \frac{1}{{T + 2}}\frac{{L^{s + 1} (1 - L)^{T - s + 1}  - R^{s + 1} (1 - R)^{T - s + 1} }}{{\int_L^R {z^s (1 - z)^{T - s} dz} }}
$$ via [this](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17.E20) identity.

Comment: Thanks @Gary :-)