# Simplifying a ratio of incomplete beta functions

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, recreational-mathematics, special-functions

Can the following be simplified?

$$ \frac{\int_0^a t^{x+1} (1-t)^{y} dt}{\int_0^a t^{x} (1-t)^{y} dt} \qquad \big((x,y)\in(0,\infty)^2; a\in(0,1]\big) $$

**Note:** If it helps to assume that $0<x<y$ and/or that $(x,y)\in\mathbb{N}^2$ please do!

Comment: I suppose that this post is a simplification of your previous one.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, yes indeed it is. (For any other readers, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4415040/simplifying-a-ratio-of-two-sided-incomplete-beta-functions?noredirect=1#comment9237155_4415040) is what Claude was referring to.) The incomplete beta function is a lot more standard than the "two sided" analogue I referred to there, which makes me more hopeful about getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that I would call this a simplification, *per se*, but the beta function can be expressed in terms of the (Gauss) hypergeometric function. Using the notation of the [NIST Handbook of Math Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/), we have

$$
B_x(a,b)=\int_0^x t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1} dt=\frac{x^a}{a}F(a,1-b;a+1;x)
$$

So that

$$
\frac{B_x(a+1,b)}{B_x(a,b)}=\bigg(\frac{a}{a+1}\bigg)x\frac{F(a+1,1-b;a+2;x)}{F(a,1-b;a+1;x)}
$$

This doesn't seem like much of an improvement, but there are no integrals. Some further simplification may accrue by noting that

$$
F(a,b;c;x)=(1-x)^{c-a-b}F(c-a,c-b;c;x)
$$

especially in light of the fact that $c=a+1$ in both cases. Finally, there are all kinds of identities for specific values or relations between $a,b,c$ that may provide solutions for particular values of your parameters.

Comment: If instead we had the same function inside the 2 integrals but the numerator is integrated from $0$ to $x$ while the numerator integrated from $x$ to $1$, is there a way of simplifying that? thanks.

Comment: On a related note, what would happen if we kept the OP as is except that instead of 1 in the exponent we had an arbitrary constant $k$?thanks